# Embedded YouTube video in a UIWebView fails to play

Tags: html, ios, swift, uiwebview

I wanted to implement a `UITableView` with `custom Cell` which uses a `UIWebView`, but my problem is that UIWebView does not show video. I tried to repeat after a lesson https://w%20ww.youtube.com/watch?v=rcVv1N1hReQ, but it is impossible.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Code

```
var testArray = ["https://www.youtube.com/embed/W7qWa52k-nE", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/vH7i-qpoFVk", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/V_GTrL-UVmE"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return testArray.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! WebViewTableViewCell

        cell.videoWeb.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true

        let embededHTML = "<html><body><iframe src=\"\(testArray[indexPath.row])?playsinline=1\" width=\"'\(cell.videoWeb.frame.width)'\" height=\"'\(cell.videoWeb.frame.height)'\" frameborder=\"10\" allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>"

        cell.videoWeb.loadHTMLString(embededHTML, baseURL: NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleURL)
        cell.videoWeb.scrollView.scrollEnabled = false

        return cell
    }
```

> Screenshot

[image]

> Test Project

[test project link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/89ure2ssv5w9ssc/WebVideo.zip?dl=0)